# Should 私の be omitted?

Tags: grammar, translation, sentence, ellipsis, first-person-pronouns

I have the following sentence on my Japanese LinkedIn page:

私 の 目的 は 主導 と 代表的 な 執行 と 技術革新 通じて 例外的 な 質 を 生むて います。 
It is meant to mirror my English mission statement:
"My mission is to deliver exceptional value through leadership, outstanding performance, and innovation."

My question is, should 私の be omitted?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Since this is a formal statement, it's better to keep 私の. But people can understand the sentence without it because they know it's *your* profile.

What's worse about your sentence is that your sentence has a number of bad word choices and grammatical errors.

- 生むています is always ungrammatical. The te-form of 生む is 生んで.
- There is a subject-predicate mismatch. 私の目的は生んでいます is "My mission is (in the process of) producing something" rather than "My mission is to produce something". You have to nominalize 生む.
- 主導 refers to an act of leading, but it does not refer to an ability to take a lead role.
- 代表的な執行 sounds like "representative execution" rather than "outstanding performance".
- 例外的な does not have a positive connotation like that of "exceptional". 例外的な質 sounds like "peculiar quality" rather than "exceptional value".
- 通じて needs a particle を.
- (**EDIT**) This is a relatively minor problem, but consider using 目標 instead of 目的. The former refers to a long-term mission/goal, whereas the latter is closer to "purpose".

A corrected version is something like:

> 私の目標はリーダーシップ、高いパフォーマンス、イノベーションを通じて卓越した価値を生み出すことです。

Or if you don't like katakana loanwords, an alternative free translation would be:

> 私の目標は、指導力・実行力・革新力を通じて卓越した価値を生み出すことです。

Comment: I feel that this "exceptional" translates into 卓越した or 真似のできない.

Comment: @broccoliforest Yes that's better, thank you.

Comment: Holy moly! Thank you so very much!  I wish I could upvote multiple times!  Thank you thank you!